# Cannot find module '@angular/core'. in my ionic app

Tags: npm, ionic4

I'm building an ionic app but when i added a new page it give me this error.

> Cannot find module '@angular/core'

when import { Component } from '@angular/core';
I checked node_modules folder, i didn't found core folder under @angular folder.
Ionic CLI version : 4.4.0

I tried to uninstall npm and reinstall it but it didn't work.

Package.json File :

```
    {
  "name": "fuberSims",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.8",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-scrolling-header": "^0.1.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your package.json file? I think there might be a dependency issue.

Comment: @Smollet777 added package.json .

Comment: you reinstall npm but have you tried reinstall your modules?

Comment: @Smollet777 no, please give me the command.

Comment: `npm intall` in your project directory will reinstall all your node modules according to package.json

Comment: @Smollet777 when excute npm install it gives this error "npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/material@^4.1.3
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'fuberSims'"

Comment: @Smollet777 i searched this error and run "npm install https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/tarball/v3.5.0" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by delete node_modules folder from my project and run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this because from an ionic native plugin I had a `/ngx` at the end of the `import statement`. Removing the `/ngx` part solved it for me.