# Ionic 4 cordova build

Tags: ionic4

When try to build android app on ionic 4 using cordova build getting an error
Target 'ionic-cordova-build' could not be found in project 'app'.

`ionic cordova build android`

```
Target 'ionic-cordova-build' could not be found in project 'app'.
Error: Target 'ionic-cordova-build' could not be found in project 'app'.
    at Architect._getProjectTarget (F:\Calibre\ionic4-start-theme-master\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:90:19)
    at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (F:\Calibre\ionic4-start-theme-master\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:97:29)
```

Comment: see your info by running : ionic info

Comment: [ERROR] Error loading @ionic/angular-toolkit package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular-toolkit/package'
Ionic:
ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\rahoo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-alpha.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.6.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.6.8
   @angular/cli                  : 6.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed

Comment: does the app work when you run : ionic serve ?

Comment: ionic serve is working

Comment: Have you added android as a platform to ionic app using - ionic cordova platform add android

Comment: Platform android already exists. message when running the comment

Comment: @rahoof check this answer it tells to delete node modules in your project and run npm install again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486662/cannot-find-module-angular-core-in-my-ionic-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `npm install` in command line within your project directory (the one with package.json in), sounds like you haven't downloaded your node modules.